# MVC Core Add multiple table/form in the clientside, how to retrieve data from server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Need your help once again with MVC Core 2.0.
So I am creating a page which an admin can add number of students into the system. Basically the page is something like this

```
Number of Students: [DropdownList] // Can choose from 1 to 6

Student Form

Name: [TextBox]
Address:[TextBox]
Age:[TextBox]

[Add Button]
```

The problem is that the HTML Student Form, the name, address and age are all single textbox. What I am trying to do right now is to use JavaScript, to create form, basically in the clientside when the admin select two students in the dropdownlist then I will parse/add in the additional student form table something like.

`data = "<table>... </table>"`

However, the problem is that in the server-side how do I retrieve the data? Because it's all HTML code for the 2nd table/form onwards. Only the first student form that has @Html.TextBoxFor something like that. I am looking for suggestions on how to solve this problem, not directly provide me the code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a view model with properties for Name,Address Age. Use `IEnumerable<YourStudentViewModel>` as your action method parameter. As long as the input element names matches with the property names, model binding will work.

Comment: You need to share how you are dynamically creating the input elements in client side. Add it to question, not as a comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view model with those 3 properties and use a collection of that view model as your HttpPost action method parameter. As long as the input element names(with 0 based index) matches with the property names, model binder will be able to map the posted data to your action method parameter.

Create a view model

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int Age { set; get; }
}
```

Use a collection of this view model in your http post action method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save(IEnumerable<StudentViewModel> students)
{
    // to do : use students
    // to do : return something
}
```

For model binding to work, the input elements inside your form tag should have a name attribute value like below

```
<input type="text" name="[{n}].Name" />
```

Where `{n}` is the 0 based index of student rows

Now in the client side, render the dropdown and a container div element to which you can dynamically add the student rows based on the dropdown selection. Keep this container div inside a `form` tag

```
<select id="studentCount">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<form asp-action="Save" asp-controller="Students" method="post">
    <div id="students"></div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now in your client side script, listen to the change event on the dropdown, get the value and create n rows for students , where each row will have an input element for `Name` and `Age`. We will make sure that we are setting the name attribute value like `[0].Name`, `[0].Age` for the first row and   `[1].Name`, `[1].Age` for the second row and so on.

```
$(function () {

    $('#studentCount').change(function (e) {
        var v = $(this).val();
        addRows(v);
    });
    function addRows(count) {
        var r = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            r += '<p>Name:<input type="text" name="[' + i + '].Name" />
                      Age:<input type="text" name="[' + i +'].Age" /></p>';
        }
        $("#students").html(r);
    }
});
```

The above code will create input elements with the correct name attribute value and when you submit the form , model binding will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have another problem. One of the required field to enter is student "Date of Birth" and the problem is that my datetimepicker only got 1. So when another table/form being generated, the datetimepicker won't work anymore. What is your suggestion regarding this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can re-bind the date picker plugin to the new item after you append that to the current DOM. See this working fiddle. http://jsbin.com/xizobayino/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's still not working hmm. The DateTime just won't shows up.

Comment: Compare it with the working jsfiddle i shared in the previous comment. Check your browser console and see whether you have any script errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Some Background**

What you want to do is not hard but you need to have a good understanding of web and MVC so you can make this to work. I will try and explain.

When the user requests the view, the request will arrive at your controller and your controller will return a view to the user like shown below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    students.Add(new Student());
    return View(students);
}

// Hypothetical Student class
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the razor view:

```
@model Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<form>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

That razor view will be rendered by the MVC engine and HTML will be returned to the user. The part we are interested in is shown below:

```
<form>
    <input name="Name" type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Please note the `name` of `input` above is `Name`. When the user fills out the form and submits it, it will post the value of the `Name` to the backend controller.

**Your Problem**

You are adding NOT one student like above, but many students. So here is what you need to do. When the request initially comes, you need to return a view that has a list of students but the list has only one student like shown below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var students = new List<Student>();
    students.Add(new Student());
    return View(students);
}
```

And here is the razor view:

```
@model List<Student>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<form>
    @for (int i = 0; i < this.Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => this.Model[i].Name)
    }
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Please note the `for` loop. If you use `foreach`, it will not work. Here is the HTML which will be rendered by the MVC engine:

```
<form>
    <input name="[0].Name" type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Please note that now the `name` is `[0].Name`. In plain English, this input box is for the name of the student at index 0 (first student).

So in JavaScript code, you need to add more `input` boxes like above but you need to make sure they are named like `[1].Name`, `[2].Name` and so on. You need to do that for each and every property not just for `Name`.

Then when the user posts the form, you need an action which will serve a POST request for one or many students. Here is the what the controller action should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Student> students) { ... }
```

The DefaultModelBinder for MVC will figure out that the form which is posted has elements such as `[x].Name` within the form so it is smart enough to take each element and create `Student` objects from it and then add it to the a list and pass it to the above action.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have another problem. One of the required field to enter is student "Date of Birth" and the problem is that my datetimepicker only got 1. So when another table/form being generated, the datetimepicker won't work anymore. What is your suggestion regarding this?
Thanks.

Comment: @elaineelaine please ask another question and I or someone will help you.