# Bind variable number of tags with asp-for

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a view where an user can trigger an action that will insert `input` tags in the page:

[image]

The 'Add more' button is tied to a jquery click event.

HTML:

```
<div id="details">
   <label>More details</label>
   <input placeholder="Foo" asp-for="">
   <input placeholder="Bar" asp-for="">
</div>
<button id="add-details" type="button">Add more</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#add-details").click(function(){
  $("#details").append(`<input placeholder="Foo" asp-for="">
      <input placeholder="Bar" asp-for="">`)
});
```

---

Now, I want to bind the `<input>` tags to a C# Model, in order to retrieve their values in a Controller. But there could be any amount of these tags.

The most convenient way to retrieve them would be as a `Dictionary<T>`, but I don't know what to put in the `asp-for` attributes.

So how should my `Model` look like? What should I put in my `asp-for` attributes?

Comment: Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for dynamically adding collection items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48357541/4228458) is not about TagHelpers (which you are using), please read it to give you a background of what you need to do and why.

In your case you will want to add input tags so their names are array-like with indices. For example, below:

```
<input placeholder="Foo" asp-for="[0].Foo">
<input placeholder="Foo" asp-for="[1].Foo">
```

will map to a collection and the first item's (index 0) will be the contents of the input tag with `asp-for="[0].Foo"` and the second item's will be the contents of the input tag with `asp-for="[1].Foo"`.

You controller action method should accept a collection. For example, if you were adding students, then the action method may look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Student> students) { ... }
```

Finally, please refer the *Expression names and Collections* of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-input-tag-helper) for more info.