# Can't bind data to List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, razor, data-binding

I'm working with the following View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Gestor.Models.VarTc>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Alterar TC";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Alterar TC</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Descrição</th>
    <th>Critério</th>
    <th>Var TC1</th>
    <th>Var TC2</th>
    <th>Var TC3</th>
    <th>Var TC4</th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id)

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apelido)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Criterio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Criterio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.VarTc1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.VarTc1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.VarTc2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.VarTc2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.VarTc3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.VarTc3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.VarTc4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.VarTc4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Gravar e Calcular" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Retornar a lista", "Index")
</div>
```

Which is called by this Action:

```
public ViewResult VarTc()
    {
        var tcs = new List<VarTc>();
        var lista = db.PlanejVendas.ToList();

        foreach (var item in lista)
        {
            var produto = db.Produtos.Single(p => p.Id == item.ProdutoId);
            var tc = new VarTc
            {
                Id = item.ProdutoId,
                Apelido = produto.Apelido,
                Descricao = produto.Descricao,
                Criterio = item.Criterio,
                VarTc1 = item.VartC1,
                VarTc2 = item.VarTc2,
                VarTc3 = item.VartC3,
                VarTc4 = item.VartC4
            };

            tcs.Add(tc);
        }

        return View(tcs);
```

The post Action is handed as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult VarTc(List<VarTc> varTc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in varTc)
            {
                var atual = db.PlanejVendas.Single(p => p.Id == item.Id);
                atual.Criterio = item.Criterio;
                atual.VartC1 = item.VarTc1;
                atual.VarTc2 = item.VarTc2;
                atual.VartC3 = item.VarTc3;
                atual.VartC4 = item.VarTc4;

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("VarTc");
    }
```

When, in execution I fill the form and run the action I verify that there is no List varTc. It's actually null.

So that the, what I at least believe List with the values is not handled as return.

I tried everything I could think of and I wasn't able to get the data.

How data can be done?

Does it has to do with the fact that I'm trying to read a list or it i8s just something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id)
}
```

all the html tags generated will have the same name. In this case, they will all have the same `name="Id", id="Id"`. You do not want that. Do this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
}
```

You need to do that for all the fields so each one can have a different `name`. Then when you submit the form, the MVC binder will figure out that you have many things (`VarTc`) and the binding will work as you expect.

If you need more details about the issue you are experiencing, please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48357541/4228458).